# How is Foo** an array of arrays?

Tags: c++, pointers

In C++, I have been told that `Foo** foo;` is a pointer to a pointer and also an array of arrays?

Would someone elaborate on why it is an array of arrays or how it could be construed as such?

Comment: Pointers are not arrays, they can just be used like one.

Comment: *How is `Foo**` an array of arrays?* It is not.

Answer (score 5):

It's not really an array of arrays.  However, you can access the individual elements with the same syntax as you would a real 2D array.

```
int x[5][7];   // A real 2D array

// Dynamically-allocated memory, accessed through pointer to pointer
// (remember that all of this needs to be deallocated with symmetric delete[] at some point)
int **y = new int*[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    y[i] = new int[7];
}

// Both can be accessed with the same syntax
x[3][4] = 42;
y[3][4] = 42;

// But they're not identical.  For example:

void my_function(int **p) { /* ... blah ... */ }

my_function(x);  // Compiler error!
my_function(y);  // Fine
```

There are plenty of other subtleties.  For more in-depth discussion, I strongly suggest reading through all of the section of the C FAQ on this topic: [*Arrays and pointers*](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) (pretty much all of it is equally valid in C++).

However, in C++, there is usually very little reason to use raw pointers like this.  Most of your needs can be handled better with container classes, such as `std::vector`, `std::array` or `boost::multi_array`.

Comment: And [`boost::multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html)

Comment: For every `new` there should be a `delete`! :) Never can say this my students enough. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not the *array of arrays* but you can construct `Foo**` as array of arrays in the following way:

```
Foo** arr = new Foo*[height];
for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    arr[i] = new Foo[width]; // in case of Foo has default constructor
```

To access individual elements you can use

```
arr[i][j].some_method();
```

Also it can be just pointer to pointer of type `Foo`.

```
Foo* fooPointer = &fooInstance;
Foo** fooPointerPointer = &fooPointer;
```

Comment: What syntax would you use to access individual elements of arr?

Comment: @Paul just as to 2d array (`name[index1][index2]`) - i've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

It's not an array of arrays - pointers are not arrays and hence pointers to pointers are not arrays to arrays.

They can be similarly indexed into to store and retrieve information though...and thus functionally they act a lot like an array would.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: In C++ a (variable sized, i.e. no fixed size like int[5]) array is simply a pointer to the first element of that array. Therefore, the compiler cannot distinguish if a pointer points to the beginning of an array or to a single instance. So, the compiler always allows you to treat a pointer as an array. If however, the pointer does not point to a memory block that is large enough to be used as an array, using it as such will result in some kind of memory failure (segmentation fault or silent failure).